# Python Flask getlist of checkboxes returns empty list

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, checkbox

I am using an html table to display some data with checkboxes as the first column, so the user can select multiple rows and delete them simultaneously. The html code to create the checkboxes is this:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{row .index}}"
        value={{row .index}}>
    {{row .like}}
</td>
```

I'm trying to get a list of all the indexes of the selected rows, so I can pass them on to a function which will delete the rows from the database. Currently I'm just using these two lines to get the list, but I get an empty list every time:

```
    print(request.form.getlist('checkbox'))
    return 'Done'
```

Do I have a stupid mistake somewhere?
PS. I have almost the entire html doc on one form, because it's a quite simple page and just makes things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. IoaTzimas answer was one of the things, but the `['<built-in']` problem was fixed by changing `value={{row .index}}` to `value={{data.index(row)}}`. It's quite obvious actually, because the index of row is searched for in the list 'data'. Small mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the names of your checkbox options. They are all different as you are using a variable. Try using this name:

```
name="checkbox"
```

in this line of your code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{row .index}}"
```

Comment: Thanks @IoaTzimas, I got somewhere, but not entirely there... Now this is printed: `['<built-in', '<built-in']` depending on how many checkboxes were selected. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that you pass the correct values inside the checkbox in your html file?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I saw in another thread someone said to add the `value={{row .index}}>` part, but I can't seem to find anything about that. In pycharm, I got a warning saying "attribute .index is not allowed here" at that specific part, but I ignored it because I don't know what it means or why not. I just trusted the person who said I should use the above line.

Comment: Check how you can pass values to html with Flask, you will find plenty of info

Comment: What do you mean? Like why would I send data from python to html in this case?

Comment: What are row .like and row .index inside your html? Where are they coming from? What is their value?

Comment: I thought row was related to the html table, but after looking at the html code again, I remember its the data from the database I read from to display in the table. Thanks I'll go look into it!

Comment: Any data in your html incuded in {{  }} is Python data and it's loaded in your Flask route. Check there for the integrity of that data (row .index, etc)